# How to run in-line SQL script in the command line?

Tags: postgresql, command-line, psql

I have trouble to execute a SQL script via command line, this is what I have

```
"C:\..\psql.exe" -h my_server_host -U username -c 'CREATE DATABASE test;'
```

I got this error:

```
psql: warning: extra command-line argument "test;'" ignored
psql: FATAL:  database "DATABASE" does not exist
```

I am on Windows 7 with Postgresql 9.3.

Any idea how to do that?

Comment: You should mention your OS and your version of Postgres here.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You must connect to a *database* to run a command, even if you want to run `CREATE DATABASE`, so:

```
"C:\..\psql.exe" -h my_server_host -U usr -c 'CREATE DATABASE test;' postgres
```

Double quotes for Windows, as [Craig](https://stackoverflow.com/users/398670/craig-ringer) provided: `... "CREATE DATABASE test;" ...`
Connecting to the default maintenance DB `postgres` here.

There is a better option for the purpose at hand, though: [**createdb**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-createdb.html) from the command-line directly.

Comment: Thanks. Your point is correct. And I need to use double quotes instead as mentioned by Craig Ringer.

Answer (score 1):

Windows's `cmd.exe` expects double quotes on arguments, not single quotes.

```
"CREATE DATABASE test;"
```

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2010/09/17/10063629.aspx

Comment: I got this error "psql: FATAL:  database "<username>" does not exist", <username> is the username I passed in and it seems the command picked the username as the database name

Comment: Yes, it does *by default*. If you want a different DB name, specify it on the command line with the `-d` flag. See the manual for the `psql` command.

Answer (score 1):

> Use the following script to execute the query:

```
@echo off
SET server=my_server_host
SET database=my_db_name
SET port=my_db_port
SET username=my_user_name
SET query="CREATE DATABASE test;"
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('chcp ^|find /c "932"') do @ SET CLIENTENCODING_JP=%%a
if "%CLIENTENCODING_JP%"=="1" SET PGCLIENTENCODING=SJIS
if "%CLIENTENCODING_JP%"=="1" SET /P PGCLIENTENCODING="Client Encoding [%PGCLIENTENCODING%]: "
REM Run psql
"C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.3\bin\psql.exe" -h %server% -U %username% -d %database% -p %port%  -c %query%
pause
```